# Почему не работает регулярное выражение-знаки пунктуации

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Почему не сопоставляет знаки пунктуации и подобное в шаблоне регулярного выражения:

```
# Program "as if"
import re
if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = '!'
    # pattern=re.compile("""-!"#$%&'()* ,./:;<=>?@[\\\]_`{|}~""")  # Знаки пунктуации - так не работает
    pattern = re.compile("!")  # так работает
    m = pattern.match(text, 0)
    print(m)  # при длинном паттерне m = None
```

Comment: Очевидно, потому что некоторые из знаков являются частью синтаксиса регулярок и их надо экранировать

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), чтобы заэкранировать специальные для регулярных выражений символы в строке:

```
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, 'какие-то символы')))
```

Если ваша задача именно знаки пунктуации найти, то можно использовать `\p{P}` выражение, поддерживаемое [regex модулем](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Например, [`regex.sub(r'\p{P}+', '', text)` удаляет пунктуацию из текста](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279).

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
import re
if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = '-'
    pattern = re.compile(r'[\[\!\.\,\:\-]+')  # Знаки - так не работает
    #  pattern=re.compile("!")  # так работает
    m = pattern.match(text,0)
    print(m)  # при r паттерне m = not None
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш первый шаблон — [`` -!"#$%&'()* ,./:;<=>?@[\]_`{|}~ ``](https://regex101.com/r/Bs7zTm/1) — находит только `}~`, так как `|` разбивает весь шаблон на две альтернативы, и первая из них (`` -!"#$%&'()* ,./:;<=>?@[\]_`{ ``) не найдёт никакого совпадения в связи с тем, что внтри  находится знак конца строки `$`.

В общем, чтобы исправить шаблон, необходимо

1) заключить весь шаблон в квадратные скобки `[...]`;
 2) экранировать знак `]` (или поместить сразу после открывающей квадратной скобки). **Обратите внимание**: кроме него нужно экранировать `\` (всегда), `-` (если он не в начале/конце символьного класса или же после валидного диапазона), `^` (если стоит в начале позитивного - как в  вопросе - символьного класса). Не нужно обязательно пользоваться `re.escape`, хотя этот метод будет работать.

Используйте

```
r'''[-!"#$%&'()* ,./:;<=>?@[\\\]_`{|}~]'''
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/7OgsQj/1)

[Пример на Python](https://ideone.com/FzInc2):

```
import re
s="""-!"#$%&'()* ,./:;<=>?@[\]_`{|}~TEXT"""
pattern=r'''[-!"#$%&'()* ,./:;<=>?@[\\\]_`{|}~]'''
print(re.sub(pattern, '', s)) # => TEXT
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
# => ['-', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', ' ', ',', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']
```